# Symfony2/3 - Multiple file input check if is empty

Tags: php, symfony

How to check if multiple file input is empty? 
I tried this

```
if (empty($_FILE["file"]["name"]))
   die('is empty');
else
   die('file found');
```

But it always returns "is empty". Even when a file is loaded.

```
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)
   die("is empty");
else
   die("file found");
```

This, always returns "file found".

Comment: in first example you have typo? `$_FILE` -> `$_FILES`

Comment: Why is this tagged as a Symfony question?

Comment: @AlvinBunk because i'm using SF? And mb SF has some function for it.

Comment: @Miro Sure, i tried both variants :(

Comment: @kironet, if you don't want to use symfony framework functions (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html), maybe you could do at least basic debugging on your side, for example how does $_FILES array look, when you upload one file, how does it look, when you upload 2 files, how does it look, when you upload no file ?

Answer (score 0):

What I did in My Project:

```
        foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
        {
            if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][$key])){

                if($_FILES['file']['size'][$key]>0){

                       //desired code

         }
                }
             }
```